# Como declarar na função um componente de uma struct estática? C

Tags: c, struct

No arquivo .h:

```
  struct conectores {
    int entrada[n];
    int busca[n];
} conect;
```

struct conectores conect;

```
void cadastra_entrada(FILE *fp, int cont, struct conectores conect, int entrada[n]);
```

Função:

```
    void cadastra_entrada(FILE *fp, int cont, struct conectores conect, int entrada) {
int i;
// Preciso fazer com que não sobrescreva o arquivo também cada vez que entre na função
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Cadastrando:\n");
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", conect.entrada[i]);
    }        
    fprintf(fp," - padrão ");
    fprintf(fp, "%d", cont);
fprintf(fp, "\n");
```

}

Chamada da função:

```
int main() {

int i, aux, op = 0;
int dig = 0;
int cont = 0;
int fim = 1;
FILE *fp;

struct conectores conect;

fp = fopen("conectores.txt", "rw");

// Leitura dos conectores
    aux = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        scanf("%d", &conect.entrada[i]);
        printf("%d ", conect.entrada[i]);
    // Verifica se é 0 0 0 0 0 
        if (conect.entrada[i] == 0) {
            aux++;
            if (aux == n) {
                fim = 0;
                printf("FIM\n");
            } else {
                fim = 1;
            }   
        }
    }
    printf("Saí do for\n");
    while (fim != 0) {
    // Pega cada caracter e armazena em dig, busca se tem no arquivo 
    while ((dig = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        printf("Entrei no while\n");
        i = 0;
        conect.busca[i] = dig;
        if (conect.busca[i] == conect.entrada[i]) {
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("Conector não encontrado. Gostaria de cadastrá-lo? s(1) ou n(2) \n");
            scanf("%d\n", &op);

            switch(op) {
                case(1):
                    cont = cont++;
                    cadastra_entrada(fp, cont, conect, entrada);
                    break;
                case(2):
                    printf("Novo padrão não cadastrado\n");
                    //imprime_inverso();
                    return 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Opção inválida\n");
                    break;
            }
        // Pula pra próxima linha para procurar na próxima linha ?????
            fscanf(fp, "\n");
        }



// inverte_valores(conect);
// imprime_inverso();
    }
    printf("t\n"); 
fclose(fp);
}
```

}

Mas ainda dá a mensagem de que a entrada não está declarada.
Tentei com ponteiro, como vetor, só como 'int entrada' e ainda não deu.

Obrigada.

Comment: Mas você fez o include do h no cabeçalho do seu arquivo .c? Exemplo: `#include "Lib.h"`

Comment: Uhum :/ Se não não ia estar dando bem mais erros, da struct etc. Mas é só essa variável que não estou conseguindo passar por referência.

Comment: Mostra a função que faz a chamada de `cadastra_entrada()`; a variável `entrada` tem de estar definida dentro dessa função (ou ser global, o que é má ideia)

Comment: Está no main mesmo. Editei a descrição da pergunta com o programa.

Comment: Na função `main()` não existe nenhuma variavél `entrada`. O que existe é `conect.entrada[X]`.

Answer (score 1):

Tira a definição da variável `conect` do ficheiro h.

```
// ficheiro h
struct conectores {
    int entrada[n];
    int busca[n];
}; // sem definicao de variaveis deste tipo
```

Passa essa definição para o ficheiro c.

```
// ficheiro c
struct conectores conect; // define a variavel conect,
                          // possivelmente dentro da função main()
```

Comment: Mas quando eu declarar na função, eu declaro como: void cadastra_entrada(FILE *fp, int cont, struct conectores conect, int entrada) mesmo? Pq ele ainda está dizendo que na chamada da função a variável 'entrada' não está declarada

Comment: conectores.c:82:42: error: ‘entrada’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       cadastra_entrada(fp, cont, conect, entrada);

Comment: Na função você tem que declarar uma variável com o tipo da sua struct assim: `void cadastra_entrada(FILE *fp, int cont, conect NomeVar, int entrada)`

Answer (score 0):

Quando você define uma estrutura assim:

```
struct ponto {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Você pode declarar uma variável desse tipo assim:

```
struct ponto variavel;
```

Depois você pode acessar os números `x` e `y` assim:

```
variavel.x = 10;
variavel.y = 20;
printf("coordenada x do ponto: %d\n", variavel.x);
printf("coordenada y do ponto: %d", variavel.y);
```

O trecho de código acima vai imprimir o seguinte:

> coordenada x do ponto: 10
>
> coordenada y do ponto: 20

Mas no seu caso a estrutura é definida assim:

```
struct conectores {
    int entrada[n];
    int busca[n];
} conect;
```

Primeiro que dessa forma você está definindo uma estrutura (chamada `conectores`) e depois declarando uma variável (chamada `conect`) com esse tipo, logo você não precisa escrever `struct conectores conect;` no `main`. Segundo que no seu código você não mostra algo do tipo `#include "nome_do_arquivo_que_define_conectores.h"` ou qualquer coisa do tipo. Além disso, onde está definido o `n` que você usa na estrutura `conectores`?

Agora vamos ver a sua função de cadastro. Ela está prototipada assim:

```
void cadastra_entrada(FILE *fp, int cont, struct conectores conect, int entrada[n]);
```

Porém quando você fornece o código da função você especifica o parâmetro `entrada` assim: `int entrada`, sendo que no protótipo da função você coloca colchetes. Afinal, o que representa o parâmetro `entrada`? O que você quis dizer com isso? O parâmetro `conect` já vem com uma `entrada`. Veja o trecho abaixo onde você chama a função `cadastra_entrada`.

```
switch(op) {
    case(1):
        cont = cont++;
        cadastra_entrada(fp, cont, conect, entrada);
        break;
...
```

Aqui você passa `entrada` para a função sem antes declarar `entrada` assim:

```
int entrada[n];
// faz algo com entrada
cadastra_entrada(fp, cont, conect, entrada);
```

ou assim (não sei qual você quis dizer):

```
int entrada;
// faz algo com entrada
cadastra_entrada(fp, cont, conect, entrada);
```

Lembre-se que a estrutura `conectores` já define uma `entrada` mas você diz que tem outra `entrada` separada. Era isso que você quis dizer?